# How to adjust my rasters converted into non-squared arrays as my CNN input shape

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I have 6 rasters of landslide parameters (each with 1 band only) that I converted into numpy arrays and stack them into the shape of (1612, 2885, 6), and 1 raster of landslide inventory as target with shape of
(1612, 2885, 1).

I have an issue since the shape is non-squared arrays, i am confused in defining the input shape of my CNN.

Should I resize my arrays smaller and make them squared? I have tried defining my input shape with the size of my arrays but this error always occurred:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: 
expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 2885, 6)
```

Could anyone help me to find a solution to the problem? I have been stuck with this issue for a month.

I am also open for suggestions on how to learn more about this input shape, so i can solve similar problems in the future.

This are the code i have used:

```
**#Reading raster stack**
Elevation = gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/Elevation.tif")  
Wetness= gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/Wetness.tif") 
Slope= gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/Slope.tif")
Distanceroad= gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/DistanceRoad.tif") 
Distanceriver= gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/DistanceRiver.tif") 
Aspect= gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/Aspect.tif")
Target= gdal.Open(r"C:/Users/Neo/NEO/Belajar Python/S3/Data jadi/Resampled data/inventory.tif") 

**#Read raster as array**
ElevationArray = np.array(Elevation.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
WetnessArray = np.array(Wetness.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
SlopeArray = np.array(Slope.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
DistanceRoadArray = np.array(Distanceroad.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
DistanceRiverArray = np.array(Distanceriver.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
AspectArray = np.array(Aspect.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
TargetArray = np.array(Target.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

**#Array stacking**
Dataarray = np.dstack((ElevationArray,WetnessArray,SlopeArray,DistanceRoadArray,DistanceRiverArray,AspectArray))

print(Dataarray.shape)
```

(1612, 2885, 6)

```
**#Target and factor array**
row = Dataarray.shape[0]
col = Dataarray.shape[1]
bands = Dataarray.shape[2]

X_data = Dataarray
y_data = TargetArray

**#data split into X and Y**
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_data, y_data, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
```

(1128, 2885, 6) (484, 2885, 6) (1128, 2885) (484, 2885)

```
# CNN model #

inputshape = (row, col, bands)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(6, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=inputshape[1:]))
model.add(MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(50, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(15, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
             optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

def lr_scheduler(epoch):
    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        K.set_value(optimizer.lr, K.eval(optimizer.lr) * 0.1)
    return K.eval(optimizer.lr)

reduce_lr = LearningRateScheduler(lr_scheduler)
EarlyStop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=200, verbose=0, mode='min')
modelcheck = ModelCheckpoint('CNN_model.h5', monitor='val_acc',
        verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')

callable = [modelcheck, reduce_lr, EarlyStop]

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=100, 
    callbacks=callable, verbose=2, epochs=10)

model.save('CNN_model.h5')

print(model.summary())
```

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 2885, 6)
```

Comment: The problem is not being non-square, the problem is that your data needs to have 4 dimensions: (samples, width, height, channels), seems the channels dimension is missing, set it to one.

Comment: Hey Dr. Snoopy, i did this before but got an error like this, ValueError: Shapes (None, 2885) and (None, 1) are incompatible.